# Unable to edit a new Custom Taxonomy in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have just registered a new [Custom Taxonomy in Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Registering_a_taxonomy) (as per the docs). Here is a copy of the code in `functions.php` for reference:

```php
function people_init() {
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'people',
        'post',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'People' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'person' ),
            'capabilities' => array(
                'assign_terms' => 'edit_guides',
                'edit_terms' => 'publish_guides'
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'people_init' );
```

As you can see in the image below, the Taxonomy appears within left-hand navigation but when my (admin) user clicks on the option I am displayed with an **You are not allowed to edit this item.** error:

[image: Preview of the error]

Can anyone suggest why this may be?

Answer (score 9):

Almost as soon as I posted this I realised it is the `capabilities` array. Removing this, so that it reverts to the default allows access as intended.

After further investigation I found that the following was the best settings to get this functioning correctly:

```
'capabilities' => array(
    'manage__terms' => 'edit_posts',
    'edit_terms' => 'manage_categories',
    'delete_terms' => 'manage_categories',
    'assign_terms' => 'edit_posts'
)
```

Comment: Actually... doing this allows the 'New Tag' page to be seen, but I'm still unable to save the tags... hmmm!?

Comment: I've updated the post answer with the code, I hope someone finds it useful.